# React Native error: invalid Java _Home with genymotion?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, oracle, react-native

This is image 1:

[image: image 1]

This is image 2:

[image: image source 2]

This is image 3:

[image: image source 3]

This is image 4:

[image: image source 4]

Error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181;

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Comment: set the `JAVA_HOME ` environment varieble.

Comment: I have! still facing same

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181` check this path exists through file explorer.

Comment: yes! this path exists. I am updating an image for my environment variables. Please check if there is any issues in them.

Comment: You should set `JAVA_HOME ` as system environment varieble not for the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this problem. Actually I have put the ; at end this is why, it wasn't executing. So I just removed it and now it's working properly.
Thank you guys for helping me :-)